# DIV height not work although have clear:both

Tags: html, css

I have HTML and CSS below

```css
.a{
 margin: 0px 150px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888888;
 text-align: center;
}
.a:before , .a:after{
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.b {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
}
.c {
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
```

```html
<div class="a">
 <div class="b">
  <ul>
   <li>DATA 1</li>
   <li>DATA 1</li>
   <li>DATA 1</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="c">
  <ul>
   <li>DATA 1</li>
   <li>DATA 1</li>
   <li>DATA 1</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

But `<div class="a">` not surrounded 2 `<div class="b">` and `<div class="c">` although I was add clear:both ?

Now I must add height for div.a to solve this problem but I don't want this.

[image]

Why and how to fix this ?

Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add:

```
.a {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

to get the parent to encompass the floated children elements.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7mo8bLym/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to parent div CSS. The parent div will automatically wrap around floats.

Check this fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoWjbK